# Laravel Eloquent One to Many relation function not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a model "model1" that belong to other model 'model2' and they are one to many relationship. Let's say model2 has two function,

```
function model1()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\model1');
}
function model3()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\model3');
}
```

Model1 has a function,

```
function model2()
{
    $this->belongsTo('App\model2');
}
```

When I call query in controller as follow,

```
function index()
{
    $query=model1::with('model2')->get();
}
```

It work but,

```
function index()
{
    $query=model1::with('model2.model3')->get();
}
```

Shows following error,

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::model3()

As I am new to laravel and I don't get why I can't called like that. Can someone explain me?

**UPDATE::**

Scenario is:

Model 1 = Room

Model 2 = Hotel

Model 3 = City

Rooms belongs to Hotel,

Hotel has many Rooms,

Hotel belongs to City,

City has many Hotels,

When I query for rooms, I would like to include Hotel and City.

I have a model "Room" that belong to other model 'Hotel' and they are one to many relationship. Let's say "Hotel" has two function,

```
function Room()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Room');
}
function City()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\City');
}
```

"Room" has a function,

```
function Hotel()
{
    $this->belongsTo('App\Hotel');
}
```

When I call query in controller as follow,

```
function index()
{
    $query=Room::with('Hotel')->get();
}
```

It work but,

```
function index()
{
    $query=Room::with('Hotel.City')->get();
}
```

Shows following error,

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::City()

As I am new to laravel and I don't get why I can't called like that. Can someone explain me?

Comment: You're missing `->get()` at the end of your statement.

Comment: Sorry I just added.

Comment: I have added some more details to the question could you please explain me how can I solve?

Comment: I honestly can't find any issues with it. The only thing I can suggest is make sure the relation functions are public (`public function`..)

Answer (score -1):

Because Model 1 has no relation to Model 3, but Model 2 does.

```
function index()
{
    $query=model1::with('model2');
}
```

And you could do like

```
$model1->model2->model3->access_property_x
```

or

```
$model1->model2()->where('something', '=', 'something else')->model3->access_propert_x;
```

Comment: Keep in mind the OP was fetching model3 _via_ model2 with a nested `with` (i.e. `model1::with('model2.model3');`).

Comment: That's actually an accepted method: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading  see "Nested Eager Loading"

Comment: I have added some more detail to the question could you please explain me how can I solve?